# Laravel static index on Collection

Tags: php, laravel, indexing, collections

I'm trying to make a ranking of elements in my webapp.

I have this code:

```
public static function getPetPlacing($pet_id) {
    $pets = Pet::get();
    foreach ($pets as $key => $value) {
        $value->index = $key;
        if ($value->id == $pet_id) {
            return $value->index;
        }
    }
    return $pets;
}
```

Previous code makes a foreach loop, which after getting all the data, appends the key **index** into every object of the collection. In case conditions match, **returns the exact index of the element out of all elements**.

This is the Pet::get() result:

```
[{"id":1,"pet_name":"boris"},{"id":2,"pet_name":"michael"},{"id":3,"pet_name":"john"},{"id":4,"pet_name":"snoop"}]
```

With the foreach loop and the **index** key appended, it looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"pet_name":"boris","index":0},{"id":2,"pet_name":"michael","index":1},{"id":3,"pet_name":"john","index":2},{"id":4,"pet_name":"snoop","index":3}]
```

**After all this, the problem comes here**

If I call the function **getPetPlacing($pet_id)**, it gives me this result:

```
getPetPlacing(2);
// returns 0 when it should be 1

getPetPlacing(4);
// returns 0 when it should be 3
```

As the conditions match, it always returns **"index":0**.

**How can I do to get the result I need in my function?**

I tried doing a foreach inside the view I'm working on, but I think that looping over every object in the collection wouldn't be the best way to do things performance wise.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: This is very expensive logic you are doing there.

Comment: What logic is used when passing `$pet_id`, where is that `$pet_id` from?

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel way to solve this problem is to use Collection -> Search which can return the index of an item passing a truth test:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-search

```
$pets = Pet::all();
$pets->search(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->id == 27;
});
```

Comment: Sorry but It doesn't work for me :(  It says: Object of class App\Models\Pet could not be converted to int. I looked the documentation and tried it unsuccessfully

Comment: @DavidEncinaMartínez please read Laravel's documentation on Models and collections. You can't run search on a single model, it has to be on the collection of models. Also $item->id = 27 should have been $item->id == 27 which I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I didn't mention that the order was made through a scoring function called **GetPetScore()**, that I hid for private reasons. That function gave the **pet** a score based on few factors, that don't show in the previous collections i wrote. Anyway, the problem got solved like this:

```
public static function getPetPlacing($pet_id) {
  $pets = Pet::get();
  $sorted = $pets->sortByDesc('score');
  return array_search($pet_id, array_column($sorted->toArray(), 'id'));
}
```

Thank you guys for helping me :D